# Python Style.applymap and to_html not running at the same time

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have the following code -

```
Flags = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\airma\\PycharmProjects\\Vatsim_Stats\\Vatsim_stats\\Check.csv")


def path_to_image_html(path):
    return '<img src="' + path + '" width="32" >'

Flags.set_index('Position', inplace=True)  # Set `Position` as Index
Flags.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1, inplace=True)  # Drop `Unnamed 0` index created by df
Flags.columns.name = Flags.index.name
Flags.index.name = None
Flags['Flags'].fillna('', inplace=True)
pd.set_option('display.precision', 0)
Flags.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)  # Replaces 0 with NaN


def color_negative_red(val):
    if val < 0:
        color = 'red'
    elif val > 0:
        color = 'green'
    else:
        color = 'black'
    
    return 'color: %s' % color


html = Flags.style.applymap(color_negative_red, subset=['Position Change']).format({"Position Change": '{:+.0f}'}, na_rep="-").render()  # Put '+' in front of positive numbers, 0 become '-'


html = Flags.to_html(escape=False, formatters=dict(Flags=path_to_image_html))

with open('c:/temp/a.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

The problem I am having is I cannot get both `style.applymap` and `to_html` to work at the same time, it is one or the other. The `style` colours numbers in the column of my table plus add a `+` and replaces the `NaN`. The `to_html` allow the png image links to display within the table. The problem have is only one or the other will run(display) not both at the same time. Is there a way of getting them to both run?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just reformat the column that contains the path to the image and then run `applymap`. This way you don't need to call the `to_html` method.

E.g. run the following line before calling `applymap`:

```
Flags["col_with_path"] = Flags["col_with_path"].apply(lambda x: path_to_image_html(x))
```